# Finding the last two digits of $17^{198}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> **Question 1:** What are the last two digits of $17^{198}$?

**My Attempt:** The pdf hinted to reduce it via mod $100$. So my work is as follows:

Since $17^2\equiv289\equiv-11\mod100$, we have$$17^{198}\equiv (-11)^{99}\equiv-11^{99}\mod100$$
However, I'm not sure how to compute $-11^{99}$ without too much of a hassle.

> **Questions:**

1. How do you complete this problem?
2. Why use mod $100$? Why not mod $50$ or some other number?

Comment: You want to use $-1$ rather than $-11$.  But working in mod 10 will only give you the last digit.  A number mod 100 gives the last 2 digits.

Comment: The hint was to work mod 100 but you used mod 10

Comment: @RSerrao That mod $10$ thing was just a stupid mistake made by me... It should be fixed now...

Comment: Try doing mod $100$ of a few arbitrary numbers with different number of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing an integer mod. $100$ consists exactly in taking its last two digits !

Indeed, if we consider $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and divide it by $100$, we get something like $n=100q+r$ with $0\le r<100$.

Now, for your example, you mean mod. 100 and not mod. 10 ...

$$17^{198}\equiv-11^{99}\,\,(mod.\,100)$$

But $11^{99}=(11^3)^{33}=(1331)^{33}\equiv31^{33}=(31^3)^{11}=29791^{11}\equiv91^{11}$

and $91^2=8281$, so $91^2\equiv81$. Then $91^{10}=(91^2)^5\equiv81^5=3486784401\equiv1$

Finally $11^{99}\equiv91\,\,(mod.\,100)$ and so $$\boxed{17^{198}\equiv9\,\,(mod.\,100)}$$

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach, exploiting the Chinese remainder theorem and the fact that $2$ is a generator in $\mathbb{Z}/(25\mathbb{Z})^*$:

$$ 17^{198}\equiv (-8)^{198} \equiv 2^{3\cdot 198} \equiv 2^{14} \equiv 16\cdot 1024\equiv -16\equiv 9\pmod{25} $$
$$ 17^{198}\equiv 1\pmod{4} $$
together imply $17^{198}\equiv \color{red}{9}\pmod{100}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First note that $-11 \equiv -1 \pmod {10}$. There's only two possible integer powers of $-1$.

For your second question, we use $\pmod{100}$ because the last two digits of any integer is exactly the remainder when divided by $100$.

Comment: So does that mean that mod $1000$ gives you the last *three* digits, mod $10000$ gives you the last *four* digits, and so on?

Comment: @Crescendo yepper

Comment: Okay, cool. And also, what about a number of the form $a^{b^c}\mod n$? How would you reduce? Is it the same as $a^b$ where you reduce $a$ and then simplify? Or is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you may want to refer to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) Wikipedia page where you are presented with some different methods. My favorite one and the most pratical is under the title "Right-to-left binary method".

As for the second question, what is the remainder of $56$ when divided by $100$? And what about $543$? And $642058311$? Note that $56 = 0\cdot100 + 56, 543 = 5\cdot100 + 43, 642058311 = 6420583\cdot100 + 11$. If you take those equalities $\mod 100$, everything but the last two digits of each number is reduced to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note $\, 17^{\large 2}\!= -1\!+\!10k\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{17^{\large 20}}\equiv \overbrace{(-1\!+\!10k)^{\large 10}\!\equiv (-1)^{\large 10}}^{\large\rm Binomial\ Theorem}\!\!\equiv \color{#c00}{\bf 1}\pmod{\!100}$

thus we conclude  $\ 17^{\large 198}\equiv\dfrac{(\color{#c00}{17^{\large 20}})^{\large 10}}{17^{\large 2}}\equiv\dfrac{\color{#c00}{\bf 1}}{-11}\equiv \dfrac{9}{-99}\equiv 9\pmod{\!100}$

Answer (score -1):

Let $G=(\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z})^{*}$. Since $|G|$=40 and $17\in G$, we have
$$ 17^{198} = 17^{40\cdot 5}\cdot 17^{-2}=1\cdot 17^{-2} \ mod\ 100$$
To find $17^{-2}\ mod\ 100$ we note first that $17\cdot 3 = 1 \ mod \ 10$. Then, we only have to solve
$$ 17\cdot (10x+3) = 1 \ mod\ 100$$
for $x\in[0,9]\cap\mathbb{Z}$, in order to find the inverse. Doing some computations, we find
$$ 70x=50 \ mod\ 100 $$
$x=5$ solves the equation and one can verify directly that $17\cdot 53=1 \ mod\ 100$. We deduce $17^{198}=53^2 = 9\ mod\ 100$